# insert data to database problems

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook, authentication

I have the following code within a file named facebook.php:

```
$user = json_decode(@file_get_contents(
'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .
$cookie['access_token']));
```

on another page i have

```
require 'facebook.php';
<p>Welcome <?= $user->name ?></p>
```

This works fine and it displays the name of the user from facebook. (clearly i have a facebook app to allow users to login to my website)

within facebook.php i also have:

```
    $id = $user->id;
    $name = $user->name;
    $email = $user->email;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO facebook (id, name, email)
    VALUES ('$id' , '$name' , '$email')");
```

This insert does not work (nothing is inserted). However if i change the code to be:

```
    $id ='123';
    $name = 'testname';
    $email = 'blhalvlvlv';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO facebook (id, name, email)
    VALUES ('$id' , '$name' , '$email')");
```

Then this works and it inserts the data into the table within the database. Why does this not work using the $user->id $user->name and $user->email ?

Comment: have you validated that $user is properly populated?

Comment: I assumed that the fact that it worked on the other page that it was being populated correctly. I am not sure how to conclusively test this though.

Comment: Easy way would be to echo var_dump($user); and see what you get

Comment: You were right. It wasnt getting populated properly. I have sorted it out. DO you want to right a short answer so i can accept it :) thanks for your help.

Comment: Had you set your error_reporting level (and display_errors) to _sensible_ values, PHP would have told you about that itself. So _please_, set this options while developing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that $user values are being correctly set.

Easy way would be to echo var_dump($user); and see what you get